# Tensorflow2.1: tf.Variable values not being updated when training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a Gaussian mixture model via TF2.1, and my model looks something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def my_network(input_dims=(250, 257), num_class=8631, mode='train'):
    inputs=Input(shape=input_dims)
    encoder_network=encoder_basemodel(input_dims)
    x_emb=encoder_network(inputs)

    mu=tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random.normal([1, 512, num_class]), trainable=True)
    sig=tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.ones([1, 512, num_class], trainable=True)

    y=-tf.math.reduce_sum(-0.5*tf.math.log(2*3.14*sig)-0.5*tf.math.divide(tf.math.pow(tf.expand_dims(x_emb, -1)-mu, 2), sig), 1)

    model=tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=y)

    if mode=='train':
        opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3)
        model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

    return model
```

The `encoder_network` (some network composed of `Dense` and `Conv1D` layers) parameters are optimized normally when training, but `mu` and `sig` are not being updated at all.

I also tried to create a custom layer as follows, but nothing changes:

```
class gmm_layer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, num_class):
        super(gmm_layer, self).__init__()
        self.input_dim=input_dim
        self.num_class=num_class
        self.mu=tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random.normal([1, 512, num_class]), trainable=True)
        self.sig=tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.ones([1, 512, num_class]), trainable=True)
    def call(self, inputs):
        return -tf.math.reduce_sum(-0.5*tf.math.log(2*np.pi*self.sig)-0.5*(tf.expand_dims(inputs, -1)-self.mu)**2/self.sig, 1)
    def mu(self):
        return self.mu
    def sig(self):
        return self.sig
    def get_config(self):
        return {'input_dim':self.input_dim, 'num_class':self.num_class}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is here since I had no problem training variables created via tf.Variable in TF version<2.0.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the custom layer, but creating the variables via `self.add_weight` (it's a method of the `Layer` class)? Not sure ATM how sensitive Keras models are to variables being created in the "wrong" way, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Did you try TF probability for Mixture distributions? https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Mixture

Comment: here an example withTF probability: https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/281

Comment: @xdurch0 Yes I have tried using self.add_weight instead of tf.Variable, but the problem remains the same

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I just looked into TFP and tried using the tfd.MixtureSameFamily method. The method from the link you provided looks neat, especially for likelihood estimation. However, I'm having trouble accessing individual mixture parameters (mean and variance of each mixture) in the TFP framework. The MixtureSameFamily method seems to only provide the global mean and variance https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/MixtureSameFamily